# What is the difference between '¿Tienes algún amigo que hable español?' and '¿Tienes un amigo que hable español?'

Tags: gramática, pronombres

I want to ask a question about indefinite words.

I was reading the following sentence:

> ¿Tienes **algún** amigo que hable español?

and I was thinking about algún:

I know that algún/alguno/a/os/as is defined as "one, a, an, any", but why would the following not work with an indefinite article:

> ¿Tienes **un** amigo que hable español?

Comment: Do any of your friends speak Spanish versus Do you have a friend who speaks Spanish. algún amigo is used to mean (in translation): any of your friends

Comment: I do not see any difference, but I see a difference in (1) ¿Tienes aglún amigo que hable español? [neutral question] (2) ¿Tienes un amigo que habla español? [surprise!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both work, but with "un" the question can be interpreted as "Do you have exactly one friend who speaks Spanish?". However, the question would usually be "Do you have at least one friend who speaks Spanish?". Therefore, "algún" ("any" or "some") is preferred.

Comment: Perfection! Thanks so much!